# Android: TableLayout changing when set View's setVisibility(visible)

Tags: android, visibility, tablelayout, tablerow

Hey guys, I'm having some trouble with a screen from the app I'm developing. When I click the OK button, the ImageButton (btnSelect) should setVisibility(GONE) and the ImageView (OkIcon) should appear, but this shrinks the space for the EditText as you can see in those screen shots.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/17/problem1ei.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/852/problem2m.png/

Why is this happening?

**CODE:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (v.getId() == R.id.init_select1) {
            if (validateSal(this.edtTextInit1.getText().toString())) {
                saveSal(this.edtTextInit1.getText().toString());
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtTextInit1.getWindowToken(),0);
                edtTextInit1.setEnabled(false);
                btnSelect1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                okIcon1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnSelect2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

**LAYOUT'S XML:**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:shrinkColumns="0">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                style="@style/styleTextLabel"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_init"
                android:id="@+id/label_init"
                android:layout_margin="10dip">
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <EditText
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                style="@style/styleInputInit"
                android:id="@+id/input_init1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
            <ImageView
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/okicon"
                android:id="@+id/init_ok1">
            </ImageView>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/init_select1"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_ok_">
            </ImageButton>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <EditText
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:id="@+id/input_init2"
                style="@style/styleInputInit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/okicon"
                android:id="@+id/init_ok2">>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/init_select2"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_ok_"
                android:visibility="gone">
            </ImageButton>
        </TableRow> (...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put weight on EditText like:

```
    <TableRow>
        <EditText
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            style="@style/styleInputInit"
            android:id="@+id/input_init1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>
        <ImageView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/okicon"
            android:id="@+id/init_ok1">
        </ImageView>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/init_select1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_ok_">
        </ImageButton>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <EditText
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:id="@+id/input_init2"
            style="@style/styleInputInit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/okicon"
            android:id="@+id/init_ok2">>
        </ImageView>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/init_select2"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_ok_"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </ImageButton>
    </TableRow> (...)
```

Comment: Didn't actualy solved right away, but using layout_weight I was able to set it the way I wanted it... thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should set layout weight for this. so you can easily do the same thing in good manner.